# Winform application program interface "Argument type is not assignable to parameter type"

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Winform application where I would like to implement some sort of an interface for the customer, so parts of the code is changeable by customer later on if they need to. I believe my approach is wrong, because I get an error in Visual Studio after recompiling my Winform application. The error is "Argument type MyClass is not assignable to parameter type MyClass", but I'm still able to recompile it. I'm worried this would break later on...

This is how I have implemented it until now:

- In my winform application I have created an abstract class with a virtual method.
- I'm "releasing" an open source project dll assembly for the customer where this abstract class is implemented and the method is calling the base method in the abstract class. If customer would like to change the method, they simply implement it themselves.
- This open source project is then referenced and implemented in my winform application.

When customer would like to change the method they implement the method, recompile the dll and replace the new dll with the one I distributed with my assembly.

My winform application has it's own strong name, and the open source project has it's own strong name.

However, when I recompile my Winform application after having referenced the open source project, i get this error: "Argument type MyClass is not assignable to parameter type MyClass". I can still recompile the project. But I'm concerned the implementation has some serious flaws and will break later on. Especially also since I have implemented WyBuild where I will distribute updates for the Winform application.

I need to provide a way for the customer to change some methods in the application without having access to all the source code. How can this be achieved if my implementation is wrong, what is your suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: My crystal ball says that you have *two* MyClass types.  They came from different assemblies and are therefore never compatible.  That cannot work, the plug-in must use the same type as the host does.

Comment: @HansPassant I believe your crystal ball is correct... I will look into this. I have a type in my winform application which is passed into the constructor of the inherited class. I guess when I recompile the projects the type are not the same anymore and therefore I get the error. I assume there are much better solutions to achieve what I'm trying? What would be a better approach to achieve the same? I have googled around for a while without finding any usefull information on the subject.

Comment: Boilerplate is to put the types that a plug-in should know about in a separate assembly.  Which both the host and the plug-in projects reference so they always agree about the type.  And you favor them to be interfaces, not classes, so the coupling is minimized.  Lots and lots of advice when you google ".net plugin architecture".

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that approach itself is a bad way to do it. To me, this sound very error prone, and you state yourself that you have a bad feeling about it. If so, then really don't do it this way.

There sure is a couple of other solution thinkable, but given your descriptions I might do it as follows, which would stay your your original intention.

Have a look at Microsoft's [Managed Extensibility Framework](https://mef.codeplex.com/) (MEF), which could help you in several ways.

Simply put, it would work like this:

- You define the `interface` that the custumer has to implement.
- The client then creates an assembly that implements exactly that `interface` and puts it a location that is monitored by MEF
- MEF loads the assembly automatically (no need to reinvent the wheel)

MEF gives you a lot of control over how you want it to work. Like, like should it allow loading only or multiple assemblies that implement that interface at the same time, or should only look for plugins only at the start of the application or monitor the plugin location during the full life-time of it.

Also by doing it this way you get rid of the custom solution you are assembling here and instead use a mature framework that provides a standadized way to do it. Just have look at some tutorials on the net, it is really easy to get into.